# Break out of loop when conditional is matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, conditional-statements

This should be very simple. Probably embarrassing myself by asking. :)
Although I'm still new to ruby/rails.

I'd like to break out of a loop if a conditional has been met.
A sale is complete when all items have been sold. I'd like to be able to use `sale.is_complete?`.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def is_complete?
    items.each do |item|
      # as soon as i encounter an unsold item, i want to return false to is_complete
      # item.is_sold? will return true or false
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: BTW: the naming convention for predicate methods in Ruby is `predicate?`, not `is_predicate?`. The fact that it is a predicate is already indicated by the question mark, the `is_` prefix is redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, looping is not the best way.

```
def is_complete?; items.all?(&:is_sold?) end
```

Comment: How to pass argument to &:is_sold?, in case i needed to, like:
items.all?(&:is_sold_above? 20)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not so embarrassing:

```
  def is_complete?
    items.each do |item|
      if not item.is_sold? then return false
    end
    return true
  end
```

Comment: That's how you would do it in C, but it's not idiomatic Ruby: 1) there is the abstraction `Enumerable#all`, 2) you don't write `return` explicitly for the last expression of a method. And the inline conditional is the other way around...

Comment: True enough, although the question explicitly asks to break out of a loop. I could give what it's "supposed" to be or I should not assume that the example code is what the OP wants to solve. As for the last line, I was just trying to emphasize the use of the `return` statement. No harm done.

Comment: fair enough. But maybe then you'd use `break`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want to loop through each item like that. This will be very inefficient. A better way would be to check the count of unsold items. For instance, let assume that the `Items Table` has a column called `sold` that stores a true or false value. Then we could do this:

```
def is_complete?
  items.where(sold: false).present?
end
```

Comment: Note that you can write a more declarative `items.where(sold: false).present?`

Comment: Or even, `items.exists?(sold: false)`